# Multi-window cygwin manager tools?

Tags: windows, cygwin

I was curious is there is a window manager where I could open one application and it will default to opening multiple windows of cygwin on my windows machine. 
Something similar to what [PowerCmd](http://www.powercmd.com/) does. Its becoming a pain to open 1 cygin for my mongo start, 1 for my node server start, and 1 for my grunt tasks, and 1 for my git motions. Then on top of that have them all willy-nilly all over the place. Any suggestions on how to manage this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can start a process in the background by adding a `&` behind the command or starting it, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to suspend and type `bg` to let it run in the background.

You can now control these "jobs" by typing `jobs`, type `%1` (1 is the job id) to bring it to the foreground.

If it prints out stuff to the console just move this output somewhere else by redirecting it, for example to "/dev/null" (the nirvana).

```
ping google.com > /dev/null &
```

Or use `nohup` instead (but be sure to terminate all your background jobs, before you close your cygwin window):

```
nohup ping google.com &
```

Answer (score 1):

Mathias Begert's answer is good enough at most of the time, but for unix fans, the ultimate tools are [GNU Screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) or [tmux](https://tmux.github.io/). They're pretty much the same, but I personally prefer tmux. It's a bit difficult to get started, but once you learn how to manage multi session, split window vertically or horizontally, then you'll become a master of multi-task processing.